# A little question of injectivity and density on $C[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $T$ be the linear map $T: C[-1,1] \to C[-1,1]$ given by $Tx(t)=\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds$.

1. I try to to show that $T$ is 1-1. $Tx=0 \Rightarrow 0=Tx(t)=\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $x(t)=0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. How can I conclude that $x(t)=0$ for all $t \in [-1,1]$?
2. I try to show that the range of $T$ is dense in $C[-1,1]$. I can see that $T$ is not onto: Suppose $T$ is onto and $y \in C[-1,1]$ with $y(0) \neq 0$. Then $\exists x \in C[-1,1]$ such that $Tx=y$ i.e. $\int_{0}^{t}x(s)ds=y(t) \Rightarrow x(t)=y(t)$ for all $t \in [0,1] \Rightarrow y(t)=Tx(t)=Ty'(t)= \int_{0}^{t}y'(s)ds=y(t)-y(0)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, contradiction. But how can I conclude that T is not dense in $C[-1,1]$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the other version of the fundamental theorem of calculus (what is the derivative of $Tx$?)
2. The image is **not** dense, because it is contained in the closed(!) strict subspace

$$
\{f \in C([-1,1]) \mid f(0) = 0\}.
$$